# Android ML Kit Image labeler giving Internal error in Camerax analyser

Tags: android, google-mlkit

I want to start my camera in my android code and then label the images it captures. The camera opens and gives a preview of the image, but its not able to label the image.
Gives the

com.google.mlkit.common.mlkitexception internal error has occurred when executing ml kit tasks

I have the following code to start the camera

```
private void enableCamera() {
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
    previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);
    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                bindImageAnalysis();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));

}
```

In the analyze image section, I am calling the ImageLabeler ML toolkit

```
    private void bindImageAnalysis() {
    ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
            new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .build();
    imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
        @Override
        public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {
            @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
            Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
            if (mediaImage != null) {
                InputImage image =
                        InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
                // Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
                //ImageLabeler labeler = ImageLabeling.getClient(ImageLabelerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
                ImageLabelerOptions options =
                     new ImageLabelerOptions.Builder()
                        .setConfidenceThreshold(0.7f)
                        .build();
                ImageLabeler labeler = ImageLabeling.getClient(options);

                TextView deviceDataTextView = findViewById(R.id.deviceDataTextView);

                labeler.process(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<ImageLabel>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(List<ImageLabel> labels) {
                                // Task completed successfully
                                deviceDataTextView.setText("Detecting Object");
                                for (ImageLabel label : labels) {
                                    String text = label.getText();
                                    float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                                    int index = label.getIndex();
                                    deviceDataTextView.setText(text.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                // Task failed with an exception
                                deviceDataTextView.setText("-----Failure Detecting Object-----"+e);
                            }
                        });

            }

            imageProxy.close();
        }
    });

    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
    CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());
    cameraProvider.unbindAll();
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector,
            imageAnalysis, preview);
}
```

Any help on why the code is going into the addOnFailureListener will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

added imageProxy.close(); inside the onsuccess and onfailure methos instead of outside.